# How do I make these two input() in a loop to avoid unecessary many input() lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to input how many victims, and then be able to input name and age for each victims.

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make a loop that ask for input for each victim. Right now I make one input and the same input is printed x times.

I can see the logic in how it works now, but I simply can't figure out how to do it without making 5 x separate input for "name" and 5 x separate input for "age".

```
num_victims = input("How many victims: ")

inc_numbr = 1
v_name = input(str(inc_numbr) + "." + " Victims " + "name: ")
v_age = input(str(inc_numbr) + "." + " Victims " + "age: ")
inc_numbr += 1

v_numbr = 1
v_one = (f"__Victim:__ \n"
         f"Name: {v_name}\n"
         f"Estimated age: {v_age} years old.\n\n")
v_numbr += 1
v_two = (f"__Victim " + str(v_numbr) + ":__\n"
         f"Name: {v_name}\n"
         f"Estimated age: {v_age} years old.\n\n")
v_numbr += 1
v_three = (f"__Victim " + str(v_numbr) + ":__\n"
           f"Name: {v_name}\n"
           f"Estimated age: {v_age} years old.\n\n")
v_numbr += 1
v_four = (f"__Victim " + str(v_numbr) + ":__\n"
          f"Name: {v_name}\n"
          f"Estimated age: {v_age} years old.\n\n")
v_numbr += 1
v_five = (f"__Victim " + str(v_numbr) + ":__\n"
          f"Name: {v_name}\n"
          f"Estimated age: {v_age} years old.\n")
v_numbr += 1
```

Added for output format example:

__Victim:__

Name: xxxxx

Age: xxxx

__Victim 2:__

Name: xxxxx

Age: xxxx

Ect..

Comment: This is probably of interest for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it up in a `for` loop:

```
number_of_victims = int(input("How many victims? "))
victim_names = []
victim_ages = []
for i in range(1, number_of_victims+1):
    victim_names.append(input("Name of victim "+str(i)+": "))
    victim_ages.append(input("Age of victim "+str(i)+": "))
print(victim_names, victim_ages)
```

Note how I have created the `victim_names` and `victim_ages` objects outside of the `for` loop so that they're not overwritten. These objects are lists - they're empty initially, but we `append` data to them inside the `for` loop.

You could use a dictionary object for victims instead if you wanted, but as Alex F points out below, if you have two victims with the same name this may result in data being overwritten:

```
number_of_victims = int(input("How many victims? "))
victims = dict()
for i in range(1, number_of_victims+1):
    name = input("Name of victim "+str(i)+": ")
    age = input("Age of victim "+str(i)+": ")
    victims[name] = int(age)
print(victims)
```

---

In the future, when approaching a problem like this, you might find it helpful to write pseudo-code. This is like a plan for what your code will look like without having to worry about the syntax and rules for actually writing it. For example some pseudo-code for this problem might look like:

- ask for the number of victims
- make an empty object to store the victim information
- repeat this as many times as there are victims:

  - ask for the name of the victim
  - ask for the age of the victim
  - add victim information into the object
- display the contents of the object

---

In answer to the question in the comments, how to format the printing, you could do something like this:

```
for v in range(number_of_victims):
    print("Victim ",str(v+1),":")
    print("Name:",victim_names[v])
    print("Age:",victim_ages[v])
```

Comment: I haven't really worked with list and dictionaries before.
I am going to write it to a text file. That I know how to do :)

But I would like to be able to pull each result and format it to look something like this:

`__Victim:__
Name: xxxxx
Age: xxxx


__Victim 2:__
Name: xxxxx
Age: xxxx


Ect...
`
Can you help me or give me a hint on how to do this?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I can't tell you how to format those without using a list or a dictionary I'm afraid, unless you did the `print`ing within the same `for` loop that you collected the `input` in... It's well worth [learning how to use lists](http://introtopython.org/lists_tuples.html), they're really useful and you won't be able to get very far without them!

Comment: I will use the lists and read the link you just gave me to learn about this.
I just wanted to hear if you could tell me if I should do something like `target.write("__Victim 1:__ \n" + "Name: " + victim_names[0] + "\nAge: " + victim_ages[0])`

And write that multiple times for each victim number I want written to the file.

Comment: Worked perfect!! and now I have a start understanding of how lists and for loops works. I can read up on those and use this as a starting point to play around with it and get comfortable using it. Question closed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Loop is used for code that needs to be run multiple times, therefore if you need to ask for number of victims once, but then enter multiple `name`'s and `age`'s, you can do it like this:

```
number_of_victims = int(input("Enter the number of victims: "))
victims = []
for i in range(number_of_victims):
    name = input("Victim #{} name: ".format(i+1))
    age = input("Victim #{} age: ".format(i+1))
    victims.append([name, age])
```

This way you get a list, where each element is a list of name and age. Now you can access file number `i` with `victims[i-1]` (because list indices start with 0).

Another option would be using a dictionary:

```
number_of_victimes = int(input("..."))
victims = {}
for i in range(number_of_victims):
    name = input("...")
    age = input("...")
    victims[i] = [name, age]
```

You can access file number `i` with `victims[i-1]` (because `range` starts at 0 as well) but you can change this if you write `for i in range(1, int(number_of_victims)+1):`. Now each dictionary key is the "human" index (starting from 1), instead of "computer's" index (starting from 0), so you can access the same file number `i` using `victims[i]`.

Alternatively, you could make a dictionary where each key is the name of the victim, but **in case you ever have 2 identical names, the previous key-value pair you have added using that name will get overwritten**:

```
number_of_victimes = int(input("..."))
victims = {}
for i in range(number_of_victims):
    name = input("...")
    age = input("...")
    victims[name] = int(age)
```